# Count total children divs inside a container

Tags: jquery, count

I want to count the total divs inside a container and toggle their visibilities with structure like this. Please also note that the div.content may also reside inside another nested or even nested-nested containers. That's why I handle it with jquery to add div.topmost for each topmost parent container:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="counter">There are 3 div.contents inside the container below</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"> 1 </div>
    <div class="container"> <!--container inside container -->
      <div class="content"> 2 </div>
      <div class="content"> 3 </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="counter">There are 5 div.contents inside the container below</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content"> 1 </div>
    <div class="content"> 2 </div>
    <div class="content"> 3 </div>
    <div class="content"> 4 </div>
    <div class="content"> 5 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the jquery:

```
  // only grab the top most container
  $('#parent > .container').addClass('topmost');
    var topMost = $(".topmost");
    var totContent = topMost.children('.content').size();

    if (topMost.length > 0) {
      topMost.before('<div class="toggle">There are ' + totContent + ' div.contents inside the container below</div>');
    }

   topMost.hide();

  $('#parent > .counter').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.topmost').toggle();
    //alert(totContent);
     return false;
  });
```

But I can't make it work to loop for each div.counter. The counter always shows all div.content. So placing the each function is suspected to be the problem.

Any hep would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try:

```
 // only grab the top most container
  $('#parent > .container').addClass('topmost');
    var topMost = $(".topmost");

    topMost.each(function(){
      var totContent = $(this).find('.content').size();

      if (totContent > 0) {
        $(this).before('<div class="toggle">There are ' + totContent + ' div.contents inside the container below</div>');
      }

   })

   topMost.hide();

  $('#parent > .counter').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.topmost').toggle();
    //alert(totContent);
     return false;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but it ignores the div.content inside the nested or nested-nested container. It only counts the top level div.content, but not the nested contents. Almost there. Thanks

Comment: But changing children to find did the trick! Thanks. Please change the children to to find, so I can mark your answer for my question. I need that each function badly :)

Answer (score 0):

To grab the topmost container you can do

```
$("#parent > div.container").eq(0);
```

I think the following will do it for you

```
$('#parent > div.counter').click(function() {
    var container = $(this).next('div.container').toggle();
    var totContent = container.find("div.content").length;
    alert (totContent);
     return false;
  });
```

***Edit***

```
$("#parent > div.container").each(function(){
    var currentElem = $(this);
    var totContent = currentElem.find("div.content").length;
    currentElem.before('<div class="toggle">There are ' + totContent + ' div.contents inside the container below</div>'
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I expect to output the count outside click event. Any hint?

Comment: Thanks, exactly like @Reigel. And His reply did the trick, only missed the "children" for "find".

Answer (score 0):

```
var topmost = $('#parent > .container');
var totContent = topmost.find('.content').length;
if (topMost.length > 0) {
    topmost.before('<div class="toggle">There are ' + totContent + ' div.contents inside the container below</div>');
}
```

etc

Comment: This still only counts the overall total div.content in the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with below code:

```
$("#parent").each(function() {
var total = $(this).find("div").length;
});
```